# How to echo the results in PHP

Tags: php, post, submit, isset

I need to be able to display the results of the submitted form with radio buttons. I want the ID to display with either of the results '1' or '2' from the radio button values.

i.e. ID: 13 - Value: 2

if the row id is set within name the radio buttons work fine but I'm not sure how to display the results from it

if the name of the radio button is set to 'ans' it links all radio buttons together, when I want them working per id

Please see my below code to explain a little better - I'm just not sure how to echo this

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM 'tz_todo' ORDER BY 'position' ASC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table border='1' width='100%' bordercolor='#000000' style='border-collapse: collapse'><tr class='t1' bgcolor='#00204F'><th>
    <font color='#FFFFFF'>ID</font></th><th><font color='#FFFFFF'>CHECK</font></th>
        <th width='50'>
        <font color='#FFFFFF'>OK</font></th><th width='50'><font color='#FFFFFF'>FAIL</font></th></tr>";
    // output data of each row
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>
            <p align='center'>" . $row["id"] . "</td><td>
            <p align='center'>" . $row["text"] . "</td><td align='center' width='50'><input type='radio' name='" . $row["id"] . "' value='1'><br></td>
            <td align='center' width='50'><input type='radio' name='" . $row["id"] . "' value='2'><br></td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table><input type='submit' value='Submit' name='submit' class='buttons'> ";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>  

</form>


<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    echo("????????????????????????????????????");
}
?>
```

I've now amended it slightly and have it generating results but now the IDs aren't linked to the two radio buttons (1 and 2)

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `tz_todo` ORDER BY `position` ASC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table border='1' width='100%' bordercolor='#000000' style='border-collapse: collapse'><tr class='t1' bgcolor='#00204F'><th>
        <font color='#FFFFFF'>ID</font></th><th><font color='#FFFFFF'>CHECK</font></th>
        <th width='50'>
        <font color='#FFFFFF'>OK</font></th><th width='50'><font color='#FFFFFF'>FAIL</font></th></tr>";
    // output data of each row
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $rowid = $row["id"];
        echo "<tr><td>
            <p align='center'>" . $row["id"] . "</td><td>
            <p align='center'>" . $row["text"] . "</td><td align='center' width='50'><input type='radio' name='ans' value='1'><br></td>
            <td align='center' width='50'><input type='radio' name='ans' value='2'><br></td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table><input type='submit' value='Submit' name='submit' class='buttons'> ";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>  

</form>


<?php
if (isset($_POST['ans'])) {
    $answer = $_POST['ans'];
    if ($answer == "1") {
        echo 'OK';
    } elseif ($answer == "2") {
        echo 'FAIL';
    }
}
?>
```

Please let me know if you would like me to explain a little better or differently

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: what´s exactly the problem? what´s happening when you hit radio1 or radio2 and submit the form?

Comment: if the row id is set within name the radio buttons work fine but I'm not sure how to display the results from it

Comment: if the name of the radio button is set to 'ans' it links all radio buttons together, when I want them working per id

Comment: radio buttons are meant for working together, i think that you want to use a checkbox, one per row

Comment: I want them to work together per row, i.e. OK or FAIL.   I don't want them to be able to select more than one option per row.  but the rows are generated from the MySQL DB

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your problem. You should name the radio button this way for example

```
 name='ans" . $row["id"] . "'
```

This way, radio buttons will work together for each row.

Comment: then how would I get it to echo the results of what was submitted?

Comment: you will need to go trough all rows id and check them, something like `if (isset($_POST['ans'.$rowID])) {

Comment: Still not displaying anything, what would be added after that?

Comment: Instead of using the name field within the radio button, I've merged it all into the value field:
<input type='radio' name='radio'  value='".$rowid." - 1'>

but then I have the problem that you can only select 1 radio button for all rows

Comment: just testing different stuff and seeing what outcome I get

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the name field within the radio button, I've merged it all into the value field:

```
<input type='radio' name='radio'  value='".$rowid." - 1'>
```

but then I have the problem that you can only select 1 radio button for all rows